# Tablet app with finger drawing that starts with black background/white pen by default

Tags: ios, windows-10, drawing

Is there a very simple tablet app that lets your draw with your finger/has pinch to zoom, and an easy way to clear the screen and save your finger drawings?

Might do some very simple math or diagramming with my finger.

Specifications:

- I use a Windows 10 tablet,an iPad Air 2 tablet, and a Galaxy S7 phone. Would be great if I could get this to work on all of them.
- Diagrams should preferably start with a black background and white pen.
- Would be willing to pay about 10$